# How can I fix error in android-studio Giraffe : 2022.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

When ever I create new project in my Android Studio this type of error will create and my application is not run. [Error will show in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKnsv.png)

I update my gradle built version and also update the version of java but the error is not resolve. What will I do know?